# Upgrading from 17.208.0034 to 18.101.0039

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to upgrade to the latest build of Acumatica 2018 R1 from the latest version/build of 2017 (with a clean Sales Demo database) and get the following error:

The database cannot be upgraded because your current build (17.208.0034) is incompatible with the build (18.101.0039) you want to install. Wait for the next update package that will be compatible with your current build.

Does anyone know which 2017 R2 builds are compatible with 2018 or is there some type of workaround or do we have to wait for another version of 2018?  Thanks

Comment: Why are you not asking Acumatica? They should know it best and can give you advice.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume update 1 for 2018R1 would work with update 7 because update 8 was just released and the code should be comparable. If you don't have a backup of update 7 for 2017R2 and **ONLY if this is demo data** I have in the past just reset my version number in the Versions table back to a previous version. Try to set yours back to 17.207.0029 (*requires access to SQL and an update statement to the Version table*)

The problem here is you don't know what kind of issues you are going to run into as you are trying an unsupported version by changing the existing version value. Make sure you test plenty before you demo if going this approach :)

Best result is to restore to a 17.207 database backup and then upgrade. I backup each version before upgrading for issues like this (local development databases).